# Why do we think of group compositions as multiplication?

Tags: group-theory, notation, math-history

This has bothered me for some time: The composition in a group is usually denoted $xy$ or $x\cdot y$. Powers (note the word) are denoted by $x^n$, inverses by $x^{-1}$, and the neutral element by $1$.

Someone clearly seemed to think of multiplication when these conventions were adopted.

But *wait*, in most algebraic (ring-like) structures where multiplication is defined, this operation almost *never* makes that structure into a group, even if you take away zero. **Wouldn't it have been much more natural to use additive notation for groups?** Obviously, when we call something "addition," it is usually commutative, but then again, this is mostly a result of conventions; multiplication was also traditionally thought of as commutative until evil people invented non-commutative rings.

**Are there any historical/heuristic/practical explanation for this (in my opinion) strange choice of notation?**

The best explanation I can come up with is that it *works*, that non-commutative rings just turned out to be such an interesting topic that people stopped thinking of multiplication as always commutative. Hence they used multiplicative notation when the group was not assumed to be Abelian.

Comment: Well, you're going to need addition and multiplication for a ring anyway... and addition is the commutative operation (whereas multiplication isn't necessarily, still).

Comment: But that is a modern convention; who said that addition must be commutative? The best answer probably is that a lot of beautiful structures arise when we assume that.

Comment: @Batman part of the question seems to be "when did multiplication first become non-commutative"?

Comment: You might be able to blame [Arthur Cayley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Cayley); he invented both matrix-multiplication and groups as we know them today.

Comment: In multiplication, many of the conventions and notations we use are probably a result of habit. I usually think of commutativity as the first axiom we must drop, associativity the second.

Comment: There's also [Hamitlon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Rowan_Hamilton) with quaternion-multiplication

Comment: The elements of a ring are an additive group. The *units* of a ring are a multiplicative group. Why would we want to write the latter using addition; wouldn't that be confusing when we can already add elements of the ring and that's a completely different operation? And that doesn't even invoke noncommutativity. What about composing functions; is $\circ$ more like $\cdot$ or $+$? Or how about constructing the group algebra?

Comment: Keep in mind that a lot of the pioneering work in group theory was done in permutation groups, where the operation is composition of permutations (and keep in mind [Cayley's theorem)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem)

Comment: @whacka, that argument can be turned backwards: Group compositions (*including* addition) are in general written as multiplication when nothing else is supposed. That is equally confusing IMO.

Comment: How is that "equally confusing"? If "nothing else is supposed" then there aren't multiple operations in play, and so there is **zero** ambiguity! Can you think of any structure with both addition and multiplication in which addition is written as multiplication? That's why we have both multiplicative and additive notations. As for why multiplicative notation should win out for abstract groups, take for instance that it's more compact. Plus groups act on things, often on structures where there is already addition (representation theory, Galois theory).

Answer (score 2):

I guess the main reason is representation theory: You can represent every group by linear operators on a vector space, where the group operation maps to the multiplication of operators. You cannot generally map the group operation to addition of operators.

Answer (score 1):

A group $G$ is a set endowed with a binary operation, the map $\cdot :G\times G \to G$ that obeys some properties. The notation is then $\cdot(g,h) := g\cdot h$.

Of course, nothing stops us from using the plus symbol for the map $+ : G\times G \to G$. But mathematicians are lazy, and a dot is much easier to write than a plus sign!

Also from a categorical point of view, a group can be thought of as a category with a single object, whose morphisms are all isomorphisms, i.e. a groupoid.

Then if $*$ is the lone object of the groupoid $\mathcal C$, a group is $\text{Aut}_\mathcal{C}(*).$ Its elements are morphisms $f: * \to *$, whose binary operation is composition. Composition is traditionally denoted by $\circ$ or sometimes even $gf$, which is reminiscent of multiplication.

Comment: Well I believe mathematician keep the + sign for commutative groups.